# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" raised when using packages "onoff" or "rpi-gpio" with WebPack

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

I wrote a Node.JS project for the Raspberry PI, to control the GPIO.
This is my first time using GPIO.

The project uses the "onoff" package to communicate with GPIO. And the compiler is WebPack.
I can compile the project without issue.
But when I run the application on the RaspberryPI, I receive this error:

```
webpack:///./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js?:178
  if (fileName.indexOf(fileSchema) === 0) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.getFileName (webpack:///./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js?:178:16)
    at bindings (webpack:///./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js?:82:48)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/epoll/epoll.js?:7:86)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/epoll/epoll.js?:15:3)
    at Object../node_modules/epoll/epoll.js (/home/pi/xilium/raspi.node/Raspi.node/dist/raspi.multi-monitor.js:809:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/pi/xilium/raspi.node/Raspi.node/dist/raspi.multi-monitor.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/rpi-gpio/rpi-gpio.js?:6:20)
    at Object../node_modules/rpi-gpio/rpi-gpio.js (/home/pi/xilium/raspi.node/Raspi.node/dist/raspi.multi-monitor.js:1375:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/pi/xilium/raspi.node/Raspi.node/dist/raspi.multi-monitor.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/raspi.multi-monitor.ts?:29:15)
```

So, I tried replacing the "onoff" package with "rpi-gpio". Unfortunately, the result is the same.

It seems that there is a configuration issue for "epoll" package (a dependence of "onoff" and "rpi-gpio").

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

As a disclaimer, I am new to electron, webpack and everything around it, but after a lot of searching, I finally managed to get it working. I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it yet, but I just got it to work.

While searching far and wide, [I found this comment on an issue from the serialport package](https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/issues/1789#issuecomment-555995162), where they use `electron-rebuild` to rebuild the `serialport` module. [More info about using native node modules can be found in the Electron documentation here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules).

Basically, I this to the scripts of my package.json:

`"rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w onoff"`

Then I ran `npm run rebuild`. Unfortunately, it still didn't work.

What was the missing link, was to tell webpack that the `onoff` module should be external.

I did it like so, in the webpack config that builds the electron parts of my app ([setup is based on this guide I read](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/building-an-electron-app-from-scratch-part-2-aaa625207c12)):

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/electron/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out/electron')
    },
    module: {
        rules: []
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        // This is the important part for onoff to work
        new webpack.ExternalsPlugin('commonjs', [
            'onoff' 
        ]) 
    ],
    // tell webpack that we're building for electron
    target: 'electron-main',
    node: {
        // tell webpack that we actually want a working __dirname value
        // (ref: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node-__dirname)
        __dirname: false
    }
};
```

As I wrote this, I stumbled upon [externals config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) that might just work the same as well.

Now, finally I can blink my LEDs. I hope this answer can help anyone else in the future that might have the same issue.

Comment: This worked! I was trying to require 'gl' (headless-gl) NPM package into my Node project using Webpack for an AWS Lambda deployment, and using @galaxyAbstractor suggestion worked for me. My code looks like: `new webpack.ExternalsPlugin('commonjs', [ 'gl' ]) `